# How can I do diff function in reverse direction?

Tags: r, diff

I have data which is hourly which looks like this:

```
> head(DF3$SPprice)
[1] 51.21 39.52 38.28 38.54 34.97 38.69
```

51.21 hour 1, 39.52 hour 2 and so on..

Here I want to use `diff` function to see the difference. when I do it, it shows me like this.

```
> z<-diff(DF3$SPprice, difference =1)
> head(z)
[1] -11.69  -1.24   0.26  -3.57   3.72  14.89
```

It auto matically did like `39.52 - (51.21)` for the first data as an example.

But what I want to do is the reverse. I want it to do it as `51.21 - (39.52)` and the same for rest of it.

Do you guys know how to make it that way?

Second question is,

diff(DF3$SPprice, difference =1) is only one difference which means only one hour difference. But I want to do `diff` for one day after. So difference = 24 sounds okay, but because my data has some missing values, it will generate problems in the end. Is there anyway I can  difference one day after for the exact same hour?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: perhaps `rev(diff(rev(head(DF3$SPprice)))`?

Comment: `-diff(DF3$SPprice)`?

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you. I put one more question in my post. Would you also help that out? Much appreciated